# Disable pointer mode for webview in Xbox UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal, xbox-one

Is there a way to disable pointer mode for `WebView` in an Xbox UWP app? I cannot use the `RequiresPointer` property since `WebView` is extended from `FrameworkElement` and not from `Control`.

This is my sample XAML:

```
  <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <WebView Source="http://stackoverflow.com/" Height="300" Width="500" />
  </Grid>
```

Please find the pointer marked in the image below.

I have provided

```
 RequiresPointerMode = ApplicationRequiresPointerMode.WhenRequested;
```

in `App.xaml.cs` and `RequiresPointer = RequiresPointer.Never;` at Page level.

How can I avoid the pointer and use controller buttons for scrolling?

[image]

Comment: You want to disable pointer mode of `WebView`? You can refer to [WebView Events table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#events), `WebView` doesn’t support most of the user input events inherited from UIElement, such as KeyDown, KeyUp, and PointerPressed by design, in other words, pointer mode of `WebView` is already disabled, I'm confused with what you are asking for.

Comment: Hey, bro. Did you find the right way?

Answer (score 3):

The contents of the WebView needs to say that it supports gamepad control rather than defaulting to mouse emulation ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/how-to-disable-mouse-mode)):
`navigator.gamepadInputEmulation = "gamepad";`

And then you need to use the Gamepad API:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/dom/gamepad-api